# Reference request for a proof that $x^2+1=0$ is soluble mod $p$ if $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I came up with the following proof $(\star)$ for the famous result that $x^2+1=0$ is soluble in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ when $p=1$ mod $4$ and wondered if someone could refer me to where else it was given.

Proof $(\star)$. Let $A=\{(x,y)\in(\mathbb{Z}/p)^2 : x^2-y^2=1\}$. Since $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ and the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,x-y)$ is a bijection of $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^2$ it follows that $\#A=\#\{(a,b)\in (\mathbb{Z}/p)^2: ab=1\}=p-1$ is divisible by four. Now, one may act on $A$ by flipping the signs of $x,y$. So nonzero solutions to $x^2-y^2=1$ come in groups of four. There are two solutions with $y=0$ (namely $x=\pm1$), and so there have to be two solutions with $x=0$, which is what we want.

Edit. To emphasize - I'm looking for any publication with this proof to know who it originally belongs to.

Comment: Neat proof, but this isn't a question.

Comment: OP asks for a reference at the end of the first paragraph

Comment: I‘ve not seen this fine proof before. Perhaps once one knows it, using that the multiplicative group is cyclic seems just too attractive…

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes that is a nice (and overkill) proof. Another nice and simple proof is that we can take $x=((p-1)/2) !$ by Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice proof! It occurs (in a slightly different but equivalent form) in Chapter 4 of Aigner and Ziegler's *[Proofs from THE BOOK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642008550)*. Aigner and Ziegler consider the set of nonzero residues $\bmod p$ and the action of the Klein four group $C_2 \times C_2$ generated by $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ and $a \mapsto -a$, which is equivalent to your action: $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$ corresponds to $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ and $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$ corresponds to $a \mapsto -a$. Here is a screenshot for extra verification.

[image]

A number of other fundamental results in number theory can be proven using similar arguments, for which you can see e.g. my old blog post *[The $p$-group fixed point theorem](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/the-p-group-fixed-point-theorem/)*. There you can find counting proofs of Fermat's little theorem, Wilson's theorem, Fermat's two-square theorem (this argument is due to Don Zagier and also appears in Aigner and Ziegler), and maybe most surprisingly, quadratic reciprocity, including both supplements.